# How to use RasPiArduino on the Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, arduino

I'm using the [Arduino Framework for RaspberryPI](https://github.com/me-no-dev/RasPiArduino) with Raspbian.  It works on the Pi 2, but the same file on the Pi 3 results in an error:

```
UNKNOWN-REVISION 0x00000000.
```

[image]

Comment: I notice that github repo hasn't been updated since *before* the Pi 3 was released.

Comment: Poking through the [source code](https://github.com/me-no-dev/RasPiArduino/blob/b956521cdd83ef5b6b51e3d34dc642a86763eb14/cores/piduino/raspberry_pi_revision.c), there's a whole class for dealing with RPi revision numbers which doesn't appear to include any info for the Pi 3. I don't think it'll work without an update. If you were *really keen*, you could do it yourself, recompile and move on. I note you've already [filed a bug report](https://github.com/me-no-dev/RasPiArduino/issues/49), so I think you've taken all of the steps possible without fixing the library.